# Unity Editor 2021.3.3+ full screen in editor mode

Tags: unity

How do you make play mode take up the full screen in Unity Editor?

N.B. There are various scripts for making the editor Maximize take up the full screen (without the unity top bar), but these do not seem to work for Unity 2021.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385610/full-screen-mode-game-view-in-editor . Is there a reason you can't just use "Maximize on Play" to get an almost-fullscreen view?

Comment: wrong link? is there another one that says it is not poss

Comment: That's the link I intended to paste. That person asked the same question as you.

Comment: I actually prefer keeping the play view in a window, because it reminds me to not assume that every player will have the same screen resolution and aspect ratio as I do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Unity Store asset called "**Fullscreen Editor**".

No idea why Unity hasn't got Fullscreen yet but only "Maximize On Play".
It's very helpful if you're working on UI stuff cause you can test the game in Fullscreen without building the game, at least that's what i'm doing. And you can maximize **any** Unity Editor window with it's shortcuts, and supports multiple screens.

Also i noticed some weird "scaling" isues? when using "Maximize On Play" when working on the UI, because in 1920x1080 (FullHD) "Maximize On Play" scales the game to x0.84 due to not being totaly Fullscreen.

Comment: i'm aware of that asset - it is quite old and does not work well with newer versions of Unity